# Por qué este input DATETIME-LOCAL no funciona en Safari?

Tags: javascript, html

tengo un problema con mi formulario, tengo un input tipo datetime-local que funciona en ciertos navegadores sin problema, pero resulta que si hago pruebas en Safari no funciona, o funciona pero no como en los otros que sale algo pequeño donde puedo seleccionar fecha y luego hora, agradezco su ayuda.

este es mi input datetime-local

```
<input 
    type="datetime-local" 
    class="form-control" 
    id="dateInitTurnFrm" 
    name="dateInitTurnFrm" 
    placeholder="Date and time starts" 
    required>
```

Comment: Según [su documentación](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/datetime-local), es compatible con la versión 14.1 de Safari (del 2021) pero seguramente no con las previas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El elemento input de tipo datetime-local no es compatible con todos los navegadores, incluyendo Safari. Es posible que veas diferencias en la forma en que se muestra y funciona en diferentes navegadores. Una solución para esto podría ser utilizar una librería JavaScript como jQuery UI o Bootstrap para proporcionar una interfaz consistente y compatible con todos los navegadores. También podrías considerar utilizar un elemento input de tipo text y agregar un script que te permita seleccionar una fecha y hora utilizando un calendario y un selector de hora.